# PL/SQL - Only one value for a person

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following table.

```
CLASS_HAS_STUDENTS (
    PER_SSN INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PER_YEAR INTEGER NOT NULL, /*These two are PKs for a student*/
    SCHOOL_CODE INTEGER NOT NULL, /*PK for a school*/
    CLASS_YEAR INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CLASS_NUMBER INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CLASS_TEACHTYPE CHAR(3) NOT NULL, /*These three are PKs for a class*/
    STUDCLASS_STATUS CHAR(1) NOT NULL
        constraint CKC_STUDCLASS_STATUS_CLASS_TI check (StudClass_Status IN ('E', 'Y', 'T', 'P', 'F')),
    STUDCLASS_LISTNUMBER INTEGER NOT NULL,
    STUDCLASS_ROLLNUMBER INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

(This code lacks some minor constraints)

Now, I need a way to check that one PER_SSN/PER_YEAR (a person's PK) can only have one 'E' ("Enrolled") status. I can't do this with a trigger (given I'm selecting from the same table) and I don't know if I can do this with a check constraint (can I use COUNT() here?). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you can do it with a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger. Do a `count` and if something is not right then `raise_application_error`. Did you try that?

Comment: Oh, not at all!! Can I do that in a before insert? If so then it's all solved. I'll go check that, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a function-based unique index to enforce this sort of thing.  You can't create a constraint as such.

This takes advantage of the fact that Oracle b-tree indexes do not index NULL data so the index will only have entries for the rows where `studclass_status` is `E`.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_one_enrolled
    ON class_has_students( CASE WHEN studclass_status = 'E'
                                THEN per_ssn
                                ELSE null
                            END,
                           CASE WHEN studclass_status = 'E'
                                THEN per_year
                                ELSE null
                            END );
```

Comment: So, this index is supposed to take a person (SSN+YEAR) and check if an 'E' already exists for that person, am I correct?

Comment: @user1231958 - It creates a unique index that indexes the `per_ssn` and `per_year` values only if the `studclass_status` is `E`.  That will prevent two rows with the same `per_ssn` and `per_year` values where the `studclass_status` is `E` in both rows from being inserted.  It is conceptually similar to a partial unique index, Oracle just doesn't support the partial unique index syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by your question.  I'm guessing you either want to:

1) *Prevent insert* of more than one status per student (in which case a trigger would be appropriate)

or

2) Use a SELECT statement to find students *already in* the table, in which case you want to do something like:

```
SELECT PER_SSN, PER_YEAR, STUDCLASS_STATUS, COUNT(*)
FROM   CLASS_HAS_STUDENTS
WHERE  STUDCLASS_STATUS = 'E'
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
GROUP BY PER_SSN, PER_YEAR, STUDCLASS_STATUS;
```

Comment: I want to prevent insert of more than one 'E' status per student. A trigger would be appropiate but from my understanding I can't do a select on the same table I'm checking.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with a [partial unique index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-partial.html). To make sure you only have one enrolled class for every ssn this should work:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ssn_enrollments ON class_has_students(per_ssn) 
WHERE studclass_status='E';
```

Note that this feature is not supported in all SQL implementations, but PostgreSQL has supported since at least version 8.

Comment: This syntax is not valid in Oracle which is what the question is tagged.

Comment: Mea culpa. I misread pl/sql as pgsql I suppose. The solution direction is still valid though, and I see Justin Cave provided an Oracle-variant.